# Python SSH: Using fabric.api as alternative to paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, scripting, fabric

I'm trying to come up with a way to replace Paramiko as a SSH client for a number of scripts I currently have, so far I came up with this draft for testing:

**ssh_handler.py**

```
import sys
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.api import task
from fabric.api import execute
from fabric.network import disconnect_all


def worker(command):
    run(command)


@task
def cmd(host, command):

    host_list = list()

    if isinstance(host, (str, unicode)):
        host_list.append(host)

    elif isinstance(host, list):
        host_list += host

    else:
        sys.exit(1)

    # run the command
    execute(worker(command), hosts=host_list)

    # disconnect
    disconnect_all()

    return
```

When executing this from another script, let's say:

**testing.py**

```
import ssh_handler


node_list = ["192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.2"]

for node in node_list:
    ssh_handler.cmd(node, "uptime")
```

results in:

```
./testing.py
No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection: ^C
```

Could anybody point me to the right direction? Why can't **fabric.api.execute** recognize the **hosts** parameter during the time of execution?

---

**Answer:**

I was able to fix it by doing this:

```
import sys
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.tasks import execute
from fabric.network import disconnect_all


class FabricHelper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host_list = list()
        pass

    def set_hosts(self, host):

        if isinstance(host, (str, unicode)):
            self.host_list.append(host)
        elif isinstance(host, list):
            self.host_list += host
        else:
            sys.exit(1)
        return

    def cmd(self, command):
        execute(run, command=command, hosts=self.host_list)
        disconnect_all()
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":

    example = FabricHelper()
    example.set_hosts(["10.200.10.51", "10.200.10.52"])
    example.cmd("uptime")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused by your code, `execute` is generally used to execute a task. But `worker` isn't a task. Worker is just a one liner that is a call to a call to run. So it seems to me tat `worker` can be deleted.

At first I was wondering what this test framework is that you are using, then I realized that it's just another python file named test!

Lastly, instead of all these elaborate mechanisms, why not just set the host in the [env dictionary](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/env.html)?